# How inject user object from startup class to controller constructor based on cookie value

Tags: c#, cookies, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm using CookieAuthentication to achieve custom login,

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
{
    AuthenticationScheme = "MyCookieMiddlewareInstance",
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Unauthorized/"),
    AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/Forbidden/"),
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true,
    CookieName="Id",
});
```

Each controller in my application is expecting an user object, which can be created using the secret id(`CookieName="Id"`) present in the cookie.
How can I create the user object by reading cookie and inject into the controller on each request.

I tried the following approach,

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    services.AddTransient<IUserContext, UserObject>(a => new UserObjectResolver(sp.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>()).GetUserObject());
}
```

But here the `IHttpContextAccessor` seems to be always `null` on arrival of request.

Comment: `ConfigureServices` runs when the *service is starting*, there is no user context at that point; no HTTP requests have been made. You cannot do what you attempting, and expect this to work. Rethink your approach.

Comment: where is that `sp` in the snippet coming from? is it a typo?

Comment: var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider(), updated the code snippet.

Comment: I suggest just inject you UserObjectResolver into controller and use constructor dependency for its dependency on IHttpContextAccessor instead of newing it  up. then use it to get the user inside the controller instead of trying to inject the user

Comment: @Psb The implementation factory function takes `IServiceProvider` parameter so you need to update to  `services.AddTransient<IUserContext>(provider => new UserObjectResolver(provider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>()).GetUserObject());` and not use the `var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();`.

Comment: @Psb Also user is not available till later in the flow of the request. so you need to rethink your design.

Comment: @Nkosi Any idea about the early stage which i cant get hold of the request object?, such that i cant get the cookie in it?

Comment: @Psb I suggest creating a filter that will inspect the cookie and create a principal of the user. AT least by then the request would have already had time to be initialized and all controllers would then have access to that principal by default. As I said before review your design.

Comment: You should [not inject runtime data](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99) (like user information) directly into your controllers. Instead inject either the `UserObjectResolver` or create a proxy for `IUserContext` that allows the `UserObject` to be loaded lazily, when the proxy is called.

Comment: @ Nkosi, you were right, services.AddTransient<IUserContext>(provider => new UserObjectResolver(provider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>‌​()).GetUserObject())‌​; this made my day. its working.. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation factory function takes `IServiceProvider` parameter so you need to update to

```
services.AddTransient<IUserContext>(provider => 
    new UserObjectResolver(provider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>‌​()).GetUserObject()
)‌​;
```

and not use the `var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider()`

I would also suggest creating a filter that will inspect the cookie and create a `IPrincipal` of the user. At least by then the request would have already had time to be initialized and all controllers would then have access to that principal by default.

Consider reviewing your design.